# How to set up a mann whitney u test in python?

Tags: python, scipy

I have a dataframe that looks like below. It has 18335 rows × 748 columns though. I would like to do a mann whitney test using scipy.stats and compare the samples that have leiden=0 vs the ones that are not 0 for each of the columns however I am confused as to how to set it up. I have included the code I have tried below. I don't understand why on the final dataframe I get a p value for leiden. Am I doing this wrong?

I tried the code below:

```
    import pandas as pd
    from scipy.stats import mannwhitneyu


# Perform Mann-Whitney U test for leiden=0 and leiden=1 for each column
results = {}

for column in df.columns[1:]:  # Skip the 'leiden' column
    group0 = df[df['leiden'] == 0][column]
    group1 = df[df['leiden'] == 1][column]

    statistic, p_value = mannwhitneyu(group0, group1, alternative='two-sided')
    
    results[column] = {
        'Mann-Whitney U Statistic': statistic,
        'P-Value': p_value
    }

# Create a DataFrame from the results
results_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(results, orient='index')

# Save the results as a CSV file
results_df.to_csv('mannwhitneyu_results.csv')

# Display the results DataFrame
print(results_df)
```

Thank you

The original df looks like this:

| Leiden | Alx1 | Alx17 | Arid3a |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 20 | 350 | 40 |
| 0 | 50 | 500 | 50 |
| 7 | 20 | 350 | 40 |
| 0 | 40 | 50 | 50 |
| 8 | 30 | 350 | 40 |
| 0 | 70 | 500 | 50 |

The output from my current code looks like this

| Column | Mann-Whitney U Statistic | p value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Leiden | 0.0 | 0.000000e+00 |
| Alx1 | 1994937.5 | 4.87711e-205 |
| Alx17 | 18680927.0 | 1.2641e-44 |
| Arid3a | 10927.0 | 1.261841e-44 |

Comment: Welcome to SO! Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77369157/edit) your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the [full text of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146), all as formatted text in the question itself. Do not post images of text. The code should be a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You have made it almost impossible to help you by providing your data as an image.  I'm not going to retype all of that just to test out your code.  Did you `print(column)` in your `for` loop to see what you're actually getting?  Do you have an index?

Comment: @TimRoberts Sorry. I removed the images and added tables. This is my first time using scipy and in combination with the for loops I have created I am not sure if I did it properly. Especially since I get a leiden row in my output

Comment: If you do `print(df.columns)`, what does that show? Does it show a column before leiden?

Comment: When I run your code (after changing one row to have `leiden` == 1), it works fine.  I do not get a `leiden` row in the output.  My guess is that your input df has an additional column you aren't showing us.  Maybe do a `if column == 'leiden':` / `continue` instead.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. I had tried to remove a column but it did not go through. Thank you so much